# How do I prevent an empty registry key from being automatically deleted?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm using Wix Toolset v3 to write a value to the Run registry key. During uninstall when my value is removed and leaves the Run key empty, the MSI engine removes the Run key. That may or may not be a big deal, but as a system registry key I would prefer if the Run key was left behind.

Microsoft suggests that I create a dummy registry value with a "+" plus in the name field to prevent the key from being removed.

Wix Toolset prevents this and generates this error - The RegistryValue/@name attribute's value, '+', is incorrect. It should not contain values of '+', '-', or '' when the RegistryValue/@value attribute is empty. Instead, use the proper element and attributes: for Name='+' use RegistryKey/@action='createKey', for Name='-' use RemoveRegistryKey/@action='removeOnUninstall', for Name='' use RegistryKey/@action='createAndRemoveOnUninstall'. Using those suggestions don't solve the problem.

I've tried the suggestions in the error message above and the Run key still gets removed.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this behavior right now but I think the docs mean to tell you that the `+` key should be permanent in some way. This can be done in a few ways, among them:

- The clean way should be to mark the component containing the dummy key as [`Permanent="yes"`](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/v3/xsd/wix/component/). However caveats apply, see the docs. I've never used permanent components, they spook me, but it may be right in your case.
- The easy way is to create the key through a custom action that calls reg.exe during installation and then just never delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input. I got it working.  I will start with a list of what didn't work and then tell you what did work.

Didn't work:

1. Creating the Run key with Permanent="yes" - I could have created a dummy value and left it in the Run key but I think that would have been sloppy.
2. A C# custom action would create the value just fine and would remover value on uninstall.  However on systems with Smart App Control enabled, you couldn't do an install and uninstall without a reboot in between.  The reboot was not requested by setup, the reboot was required to get past the Smart App Control.

What did work:

1. If you create a subkey in the Run key with the Name of "+".  For example:   Oddly enough the subkey is never created.  On uninstall however the Run key is left behind even if it's empty.